# dimension of a subspace

Tags: vector-spaces

Suppose that x and y are vectors and M is a subspace in a vector space V.
Let H be the subspace spanned by M and x.
Let K be the subspace spanned by M and y.
Prove that if y is in H but not in M , then x is in K
I am supposed to use dimension calculus to prove it. Please help
My work : 
let m is dim(M), so dim (H) = m +1
                    dim (K) = m +1
x, y linearly independent to M but I don't know whether they are linearly independent to each other or not. I am stuck here.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $y \in H$ means that $y=m+cx$ where $m \in M$ and $c$ is a scalar.

Also, $ y $ doesn't belong to $M$ means that $c \neq 0$.

So, $x= c^{-1}(y-m)$ and hence, $x \in K$.

Comment: is y a vector? do I have to put it under the form of vector? I am new to the field. Please help me more

Comment: @user73195: By your question, both $x$ and $y$ are vectors- right?

Comment: I am not sure about the dimension of the vectors x and y. What if x = (x1, x2,...xi) and y = (y1, y2,.... , yj)?

Comment: @user73195: Since these vectors belong to the same vector space their "dimensions" are equal. Though I would suggest not to think of vectors as n-tuples. Rather think them of some "abstract" objects, having some properties. A vector is just an element of a vector space. You can add two vectors, and can multiply a vector by a scalar. That's all!

Comment: I got what you mean. Thank you very much.